# Android - Set TextView outside ListView to get the RatingBar value inside ListView using Button

Tags: android, listview

I want to know if it is possible to set the `TextView` outside `ListView` to get the Value inside `ListView` using Button

examples first open app :

```
|------------------|
|TextView          | (TextView Inside ListView)
|* * *             | (Rating Value inside ListView)
|------------------| (ListView)
|                  |
|                  |
| Button (TextView)| (Button and TextView outside ListView)
```

how to set the `TextView` outside `ListView` when `Button` pressed?

examples when `Button` pressed :

```
|------------------|
|TextView          | (TextView Inside ListView)
|* * * * *         | (Rating Value inside ListView)
|------------------| (ListView)
|                  |
|                  |
| Button "Star : 5"| (TextView outside ListView set "Star : 5" when button pressed)
```

Comment: if you want to set text on a TextView you can simply get the value and set value on click of that button...

Comment: but i don't have an idea and examples code how it's work with custom adapter, can you explain me sir?

Comment: where you storing your rating values???

Comment: if it is a arrayList then on button click textView.setText(arrayList.get(thePostitionYouWantToShow)); i think thats all